# Laplace transform of products of Meijer G-function, Bessel K function and power

Tags: definite-integrals, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

I want to solve this integral likes:

$\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-sx) x^{l}K_{\nu}(2 \sqrt{ax})G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\alpha x\left|\begin{smallmatrix}a_1,\cdots,a_p\\
b_1,\cdots,b_q\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right) dx$

Does this expression have any closed-form or asymptotic series?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Yes it is. Sorry for the mistake.